# Setting a loader.gif instead of text. Is this possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery'); ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // ajax pagination
        jQuery('#navigation a').live('click', function () { // if not using wp_pagination, change this to correct ID
            var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            // #main is the ID of the outer div wrapping your posts
            jQuery('#main').html('<div><img src="images/loader.gif"></div>');
            // #entries is the ID of the inner div wrapping your posts
            jQuery('#main').load(link + ' #entry')
        });
    }); // end ready function
</script>
```

Instead of writing just text, is inserting a loader.gif image possible?

Comment: What problems are you facing with the posted code?

Comment: @RuneFSi added the <img src="images/loader.gif"> instead of the original text, but img will not load

Comment: why don't you test whether it works or not?

Answer (score 0):

check the path to the img, maybe that is the culprit.

http://jsfiddle.net/FS6P9/

Answer (score 0):

With the very sparse information. I'm going to guess that the error you get is a 404, that the image was not found. If that's the case I'm further going to guess that your problem lies in a missing leading "/" in the src attribute. If that does not solve it you really should provide more information on the error